# Adding multiple UILabels in view with constant height between them

Tags: ios, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I am trying to add some 5-6 `UILabel's` (Single line only) in a `UIView` using auto layouts. I have added `constraints` for top most & bottom most `UILabel`. The problem is variable screen sizes.

Just wants to know a better approach of adding those remaing (3-4) middle `UILables` (As I want to show equal space between all the `UILabels`).

Approach 1 - Add height constarint for middle lables & based on screen size change the height constraint constat at runtime.

Approach 2 - I tried adding >= and <= constarints but I am not getting the output as desired.

Any help, how can I keep constant height between all UILabels.

(Can be achieved via `UIScrollView` or `UITableView` but I dont want scrolling  .. only using auto layouts:))

Answer (score 1):

You can add dummy `UIView`s between your `UILabel`s and set those dummy views' heights to proportional to their container.
Or you should be able to achieve that by setting your current constraints constants at runtime and then calling `setNeedsLayout`&`layoutIfNeeded`

You can't achieve that by playing with "less than" or "greater than" constraints.

Edit: You can also use [UILayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILayoutGuide_Class_Reference/index.html) to do that on iOS9.0+

Comment: Changing constraints at runtimes looks easy to me. But I didn't get "set those dummy views heights to proportional to their containers" part. Can you explain a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use stack view from left window where you have button/label/view etc..... or also you can add it from constraints tools(see attached image[image])

Comment: Sure. Will check :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: iPhone 5s]

[image: iPhone 6 plus]

If you are looking for the attached solution, please add below constraints shown in the third image.

[image: Note * you can change the constant value as per your requirement.]